# Create highscore file for simple textgame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a highscore file in Python 3.1 that stores (already declared) username with scores. Then, I want the program to print the top 5 scores and the users that achieved them.

Currently, I'm using two files - highscores.txt and highuser.txt. What I want is for the code to find the highest integer value in highscores.txt, take its array and match it to the same position in highuser.txt.

Here's my current code:

```
def highscores():
global score

highscores = open("highscores.txt", "a")
highscores.write(str(score))
highscores.write("\n")
print("done")

highscoreuser = open("highuser.txt", "a")
global username
highscoreuser.write(username)
highscoreuser.write("\n")
print("done")
```

This code works, but I don't know how to sort the files.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the scores in a comma seperated file (.csv) with highscoreuser, score format?

Comment: Probably, but I'm still learning and not sure how that'd work.

Comment: you save username and score as follows in a single file: username,score\n (highscores.write(username+","+str(score)+"\n")). When you read the file you can simply split the lines you are reading on the comma (readline.split(',')). This will make a list where the username is the first element and the score is the second ([username,score\n]). This way you only have to open one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it

```
with open('highscores.txt','r') as infile:
    maxval = 0
    maxline = None
    i = 0
    for line in infile:
        if maxval<int(line):
            maxline = i
            maxval = int(line)
        i+=1
i = 0
with open('highuser.txt','r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if i == maxline:
            highuser = line.strip()
            break
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-n-largest-elements-from-a-list/
Just use it for 5. 
Also make sure to close your files. `highscores.close()`
And reopen them to read. `highscores = highscores.open("highscores.txt", "r")`

Make an array of all highscores by `.split("\n")`

Then similarly create a array of all users by `.split("\n")`

For each of the top 5 scores search the array for that score and get the indexes.

Then plug in those indexes into the user array and get the resulting users.

You could also make a dictionary with each user and their score and just find the 5 highest scores from all the users.

Comment: How would I then match the score to its user though?

Comment: Make two arrays of high-scores and users.
Get the indexes of the 5 highest scores then plug those indexes into the array of users.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make a dictionary of user-score pairs, which would probably be the better solution.